# Completing the where clause in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have a table `kyc3` where there are `walletno`, `status` and `rank` columns present. rank columns are currently filled with 0. While status column has following data: accepted, rejected, registered and scanned. I want to put value for each status in rank column where

`accepted = 1, rejected = 2, registered = 3 and scanned = 4`

I wrote following query but do not understand how to complete it:

```
INSERT INTO kyc3([rank]) SELECT status_ FROM kyc3
```

I understand I need to put a where clause that will indicate my logic for data population. But what should I write?

Comment: Do you really want to insert new rows or just update the existing setting the rank to the integer that corresponds to that rows status?

Comment: Don't forget to review the ways in which your records are created/updated.  The CASE statements offered will work in both INSERT and UPDATE, though if you run one of the updates and your record creation method doesn't change your data will be inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `update` to fill a cell of an **existing** row.

```
update kyc3
set rank = CASE WHEN status = 'accepted' THEN 1
                WHEN status = 'rejected' THEN 2
                WHEN status = 'registered' THEN 3
                WHEN status = 'scanned' THEN 4
           END
```

Use `insert` only for **creating** new rows.

Answer (score 3):

If the table is populated and you want to change the `rank` field, you want to use an `UPDATE` statement, as `INSERT` is for adding new rows to your table:

```
UPDATE kyc3 
SET rank = CASE WHEN status = 'accepted' THEN 1
                  WHEN status = 'rejected' THEN 2
                  WHEN status = 'registered' THEN 3
                  WHEN status = 'scanned' THEN 4 
             END
```